# TokensRegex json response

Tags: json, json.net, stanford-nlp

The TokensRegex response (web api) is as follows with an array list shaped with numerical order.
Is there way to change the format, or any reason it must be that way?
Otherwise it is hard to deserialize it or write a query on the result.

```
{
  "sentences": [
    {
      "0": {
        "text": "huge success",
        "begin": 4,
        "end": 6
      },
      "1": {
        "text": "new venture",
        "begin": 17,
        "end": 19
      },
      "2": {
        "text": "comfort zone",
        "begin": 26,
        "end": 28
      },
      "length": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) to deserialize this JSON into something sensible.

First, define a class `Phrase` like this:

```
class Phrase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Begin { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this to get a list of phrases:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

List<Phrase> phrases = 
    obj["sentences"][0]
        .Children<JProperty>()
        .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        .Select(jp => jp.Value.ToObject<Phrase>())
        .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hU4iTp

Answer (score 1):

The reason the matches are a map is to allow for named capture groups. So, unnamed groups are keyed on an arbitrary index, but named groups will have a more reasonable key.